# Does intellisense for binding works in html with visual studio code for angular?

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code

I typically use intelliJ (back-end/java) and the intellisense is working for html (basically am able to go to the definitions of the bound properties). And its doing OK with angular...

I tried to do the same with VS Code (as i am trying to evaluate is VS code gives anything more other than chrome-debugging in VS code), but somehow the intelliSense is not working.

I feel like its basic feature, probably I am missing something in my IDE.

1. Is it supposed to work?
2. Anything additional config/setup i need to make it work...

And yes, intellisense in ts files is working as expected...

**Note:**

Installing Angular Language Service extension **did not do** the trick for me. After installing and reloading  (https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service) when i tried to go to definitions its just keeps spinning (loading). Not even sure what its doing in background as i don't see obvious options to see the details.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried to install angular-language-service https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service?

Comment: nope, will try it. thank you for the suggestion @yurzui...

Comment: Did u try installing the extensions?

Comment: @yurzui: i installed the angular language service, and restarted my app. when i tried to go to definition its keep spinning (loading) for last 10 mins...i tried to open it couple of times...

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

Answer (score 1):

[John Papa](https://twitter.com/John_Papa?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor) the author of both AngularJS and Angular's style guide and  Microsoft employee (makers of VSCode) has a blog where he talks about this very thing.
https://johnpapa.net/essential-angular-vs-code-extensions/

I would recommend any of his talks or blog articles!
Regardless, the plugin you're looking for is

> Angular Language Service - This extension provides a rich editing experience for Angular templates, both inline and external templates. This extension is brought to you by members of the Angular team. It is fantastic at helping write solid code in the html templates.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

and/or

> Path Intellisense - Visual Studio Code plugin that autocompletes filenames. Hopefully, VS Code will bake this in at some point. Until then, this is a keeper.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense

Comment: +1 for the response as its detailed. However, as mentioned in the edited question installing both (ideally language services) didnt do trick for me. May be there are some limitations. i should probably open a ticket for this with VS code. For now will stick to intelliJ for development, and oscillate between chrome and vscode for debugging...

Comment: intelliJ is a superior Editor anyways ;)

Answer (score -1):

[image: VSCODE Extensions]

Here are some extensions that may be useful to you.

Comment: thank you. But, i think adding specific extension(s) that helps for the intellisense in html for angular is helpful than enumerating all the existing extensions for angular...

Comment: @Coder check out my answer above. Should have what you're looking for